# Is there a built in time how long a command took in SqlCommand?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlcommand

I'm using asynchronous `SqlCommand` to query data out of a SQL Server.

Is there a way to find out how long a query took to be processed on the server? Or do I need to capture time on the client?

I think the latter would be bad, because depending on the connection this could be much slower I assume.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could turn on Time statistics ([SET STATISTICS TIME ON](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190287.aspx)).

This would then send a message back to the client, that would look something like:

```
 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 341 ms.
```

You'd need to add an event handler to the connection's [InfoMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.infomessage.aspx) event, and then parse/display this text. Although obviously, text parsing of info messages is always likely to be a little brittle (e.g. may not work on non-English installs), but if you just want to display the text, it should be fine.